# Docker container exits when I use a bind mount (simple php/apache setup)

Tags: docker

I am just trying to get my feet wet with docker and I want to build a simple PHP/apache page.

My project is just a folder with a Dockerfile and a folder called php which contains index.php.

My dockerfile is simply:

```
FROM php:8.0.3-apache-buster
COPY ./php /var/www/html/
```

The goal is just to be able to view index.php, make changes, and see the changes when I refresh my browser.

I build the image using `docker build -t my-image .` from my project's directory.

If I run the command `docker run -p 8080:80 -it my-image` then I am able to view the contents of index.php in a browser at localhost:8080. So far so good.

Now I just want to bind mount my local folder to the container to see my changes so I change the command to:

`docker run -p 8080:80 -it my-image -v "$(pwd)/php:/var/www/html"`

Interestingly, the container just outputs some info code and quits after a second. How can I fix this issue, and as a bonus, what is a good way to debug issues like this when I'm on docker?

Edit: I forgot to mention I am on MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntax instead:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -it -v "$(pwd)"/blah:/var/www/html my-image
```

Notice how the image name comes *last*.

or, since the Docker maintainers [say](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) that most users find the `mount` syntax more intuitive (I tend to agree):

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -it --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/blah,target=/var/www/html my-image
```

What was going on with your original incantation is that: you're (`-i`) interactively, (`-t`), with a tty open, (`docker run ... my-image`) running a container which is an instance of your image `my-image`, (`-p 8080:80`) with your port-forwarding set up, and *overriding `my-image`'s normal entrypoint* (the entrypoint is presumably something which starts an apache server that knows how to run php) in the final part of your command. `my-image` thought it was supposed to *run* `-v "$(pwd)/php:/var/www/html"`, *instead* of its normal apache server, which is nonsensical and not what you intended.

Comment: This was very informative and helpful! Thank you very much!